# Marquee not scrolling in android

Tags: android, marquee

I want to use the feature of marquee in my android app and am using this code for achieving the goal:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/marqueetext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="hello all how are you"
    android:textColor="#ff4500" 
    />

MarqueeText = (TextView)ShowTheMessages.this.findViewById(R.id.marqueetext);
        MarqueeText.setSelected(true);
```

I don't know why it is not working.I have gone through many related posts but have not found the solution.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change this line and try...

```
android:text="hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you"
TextView txtView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.marqueetext);
txtView.setSelected(true);

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/marqueetext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you"
    android:textColor="#ff4500" 
    />
```

or another example is...

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marqueetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textColor="#ff4500"
        android:text="hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

are the only required attributes and scrolling even works with `layout_weight` defined with `layout_width=0dp`

here is some sample code:

```
<TextView 
            android:id="@+id/scroller"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Some veryyyyy long text with all the characters that cannot fit in screen, it so sad :( that I will not scroll"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

but the most important is **TextView should get selected** that you have already Done in your code.

hope it will help you out.

Comment: I have added the essential attributes and even now,it is not working.

Comment: have you added  android:layout_width="0dp" with android:layout_weight="3"?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

instead of

```
android:lines="1"
```

It's will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks man it worked. However, from xml it is deprecated, i used TextView.setSingleLine(true) instead. Thanks a lot