# Creating Horizontally scrollable marquee Label in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, label

I need to create scrollable marquee Label in IOS. I found it can be in Android. 
I found for android. 
[Marquee not scrolling in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486935/marquee-not-scrolling-in-android)
But I couldn't find for ios.

```
android:text="hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you"
TextView txtView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.marqueetext);
txtView.setSelected(true);

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/marqueetext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you hello all how are you"
    android:textColor="#ff4500" 
    />
```

Comment: This is not build in, but there are some open source 3rd party subclasses out there like AutoScrollLabel ( https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel )

Answer (score 0):

Use [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel), it very easy to use & implement.

If you are using `Pod` then you can integrate and try sample code as:

**Objective-C:**

```
pod 'MarqueeLabel'

MarqueeLabel *lengthyLabel = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame duration:8.0 andFadeLength:10.0f];
```

**Swift:**

```
pod 'MarqueeLabel/Swift'

var lengthyLabel = MarqueeLabel.init(frame: aFrame, duration: 8.0, fadeLength: 10.0)
marqueeLabel.type = .Continuous
marqueeLabel.scrollDuration = 5.0
marqueeLabel.animationCurve = .EaseInOut
marqueeLabel.fadeLength = 10.0
marqueeLabel.leadingBuffer = 30.0
marqueeLabel.trailingBuffer = 20.0
```

**Another Solution Using Web View:**

```
String marquee = "<html><body><marquee>This is sample marquee</marquee></body></html>"
webview.loadData(marquee, "text/html", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ZCAnimatedLabel** (a third party library) to achieve the effect you want.