# TextView ellipsize="marquee" works with deprecated singleLine="true"

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have searched a lot for run Marguee on `TextView` with `android:maxLines="1"` but not able to get the desired result. Code is as below:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Brinjal - Big(10 Quintal): 1356.00  Brinjal - Big(10 Quintal): 1356.00  Brinjal - Big(10 Quintal): 1356.00"
        app:viewSelected="@{true}" />
```

This code is running fine. But now problem is with `android:singleLine` which is deprecated now. So after making some more search I replaced

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

with

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

but now my this code for marquee is not running. I also have set

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```

Any help from your side will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486935/marquee-not-scrolling-in-android

Comment: your code working fine for me. what you want?

Comment: @BhupatBheda have you tried with maxLines?

Comment: for edit text you need to give  `android:inputType="text"` for it to work, once try the save for textview